# Priority goes back to 20 after changing it to -10

Tags: cpu, process-priority

I want to change the priority of a process in LTS 14.04.
I used

```
sudo renice -10 -p PID
```

It worked fine, but after a while the priority of that process goes back to 20.

*What should I do to get rid of this "feature"?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're missing here is a "program restart".

If you look closely you will see that the PID of the program (let's call it `child`) has been changed in the mean time.  This means that `child` has ended and another program (lets call that one `parent`) has started it again. As `parent` is still running in nice 20 its new `child` will be running in 20 as well!

Depending on how your program got started, you have a few options:

1. You start the program yourself:

   Don't use `renice` after the fact, but start your program by `nice --adjustment=-10 program`
2. The program was started by another program:

   Do a `renice --priority -10 parent` to make the parent *and all its **new** children* use that priority from that point in time.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. So if I get you right I can do as follow: 1)sart prog, 2) `renice program`, 3) restart program. But when I restart the program will change its PID again. Isn't that right?

Comment: I'll update my answer...  (Just don't forget to "accept" it!) and next time you ask a question: please think ahead and not only ask *why*  but also ask *and how do I solve this*?  ;-)  :P